# REST principle of PUT method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, rest, http

I am preparing a common and current CRUD-type REST API with the `users` model that laravel brings by default

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {

  use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, CanResetPassword;

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var string[]
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
      'email',
      'password'
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
      'password',
      'remember_token',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [
      'email_verified_at' => 'datetime'
  ];
}
```

and the routes I generate with `Route::apiResource`

```
Route::apiResource('users', UserController);
```

Since I want to find the user by the `email` or the `id` I make a link or explicit injection of the route parameter in the `RouteServiceProvider` inside the method `boot` with `Route::bind`

```
Route::bind('user', function($userId){

  $user = User::where(fn($query) => $query->where('id', $userId)->orWhere('email', $userId))->first();
  if(request()->method() === 'PUT') return $user;
  return $userId;
});
```

This is where the main topic comes in, this method (`Route::bind ()`) should return the instance of a class, if not, it will return an `ExceptionModelNotFound 404 - not found`, but I would like to be able to receive the `null` in my controller and thus validate depending on the method (PUT or PATCH) whether to create the new record (which according to REST principles should be able to do a resource if there is no match) or just update an existing one.

My `update` method of `UserController` is as follows

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user){

  $input = $request->all();
  $method = $request->method();
  if($method === 'PUT') $request->validate($this->rules);

  $update = [
    'PUT' => fn() => ($user) ? $user->update($input) : $user = $user::create($input),
    'PATCH' => function() use($user, $input){

      foreach ($input as $key => $val){
        $user->$key = (!empty($val)) ? $val : $user->$key;
      }
      $user->save();
      return $user;
    }
  ];
  return response()->json($update[$method]());
}
```

Previously I had it without model injection and the method `ùpdate` worked, something like this

```
public function update(Request $request, $user){
```

But due to the explicit injection this no longer takes the parameter, besides that I am only interested in this behavior when updating since this in the rest of the methods helps in the reduction of code and it is fine to handle the 404 - Not found.
I don't know if I'm failing at something or maybe laravel provides a better way to do it which I don't know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: The code is a bit abstracted, it looks a bit messy because I tried to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making it easier on yourself by creating a single controller action for both updating and creating users. I have never done it this way, and always define the REST routes like so:

- `PUT /user/1` = UPDATE
- `POST /user`  = CREATE

You should know on the frontend whether you are making a new user or updating an existing one (simply check for an `id` element for instance).

Also, your current route bind is not the best logic, since that `$user` query is always executed, even when it is not a `PUT` request. Nevertheless that code can be simplified much further if you just `firstOrFail()` that user since you should be separating the functionality into 2 routes anyway.

Personally I never use `PATCH`, since my `PUT` routes allow partial updates as well (e.g. only sending an `email` property update).

Comment: Thanks for answering Flame, well, I tried to do it on this way because the REST principles say that with the PATCH method a partial update is done and with the PUT method its a complete update and if the row identified by some unique column doesnt exist, its created.
About routes, I created them with apiResource method, so each operation is handled by its method, but my doubt was, why laravel with apiResource () provide two routes (PUT and PATCH) that point to update method controller? is it just to choose the preferred method ?.

Comment: And about the route binding, I just wanted to check if it exists, return a row, if not, return null to handle myself in controller.

Comment: But still, thank you for answering me and telling me about your way of working. If there is no way or it is not usual in the workplace, I will make it simpler then.